# Haskell: Types with parameters (edit: aka dependent types)

Tags: haskell, types, set

I've just started defining my own types in Haskell, and I found the example in Section 3 of
http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Type
about representing cards useful.  There's something I'd like to do and I'm not sure how to achieve it.  I'll try and explain using the cards analogy.

I want to work with different collections of cards.  Say we fix that cards always have CardValue and Suit, but as well as the standard collection, I want to allow a deck that has a fifth suit "Rubies".  I want to be able to do things like take Kind1 and Kind2 and define a kind of cards Kind3 which has as possible suits the union of suits from Kind1 and Kind2, and as cardvalies the set of suits from Kind1.  I'd also like to compile a program where the user can input the names of the suits, etc., and then we can perform some standard card operations with the kind of cards she inputs.  *What I don't want to do is just write out a finite number of different data types, because I don't know in advance what all my different kinds of cards will be*.

I can imagine a solution involving lots of lists and lots of checks to see that things are elements of lists, but I imagine it would be a nightmare to write and very inefficient.

Let me write some pseudocode that doesn't work but might get the idea of what I want to do across better than my description above.

```
-- this isn't real code!

type Suit = [String]
type CardValue = [String]

data (Card s v) = (Card s v) {suit :: (s :: Suit), value :: (v :: CardValue)}

usualSuit :: Suit
usualSuit = ["Club","Diamond","Heart","Spade"]

flowerSuit :: Suit
flowerSuit = ["Rose","Daisy","Poppy"]
```

Of course I know that this is nonsense, and I guess it goes against the principle of types all being defined at compile time (which I can see is a good principle).

Can anyone tell me:

- Is there a way to do something like what I'm describing?
- Is there a better way to achieve the same thing?

I'm also interested in links/keywords to read up on, but please note that I don't know much programming terminology or even much Haskell.

I do want to use Haskell to do this - the lazy evaluation and infinite lists are very useful to me, and I already have code written to do things.

I've tried googling and looking through a few Haskell tutorials (I'm still a beginner!) but haven't found anything useful.  This is possibly because I don't know what words to search on.

Thanks

**Edit**: I'm worried that I haven't explained what I want to do well.  Here's some genuine code that compiles with no errors, with annotations that explain what I'd like it to do.

```
import Data.List

type Suit = String
type Value = Integer
type ListOfSuits = [Suit]
type ListOfValues = [Value]

data Deck = Deck {listofsuits :: ListOfSuits, listofvalues :: ListOfValues } deriving (Show)

sillyDeck :: Integer -> Deck
-- This is some function.  For example, we might have
sillyDeck n = Deck ["Heart","Spade"] [1..n]
-- Note that this defines infinitely many different decks

-- How should I define a card in sillyDeck n?  One option is
data Card = Card {suit :: Suit, value :: Value } deriving (Show)
-- but this doesn't reference the deck I'm using.  I could try
data Card2 = Card2 {suit2 :: Suit, value2 :: Value, deck2 :: Deck } deriving (Show)
-- but then
cardInWrongDeck :: Card2
cardInWrongDeck = Card2 "Cheese" 999 (sillyDeck 3)
-- is valid, when I'd hope for something like a type error.
-- Of course, I could write a function to check that each card is in the
-- deck it claims to be, and apply it regularly, but that's a horrible solution.

-- Is there a better way to do this?
```

Hopefully this explains my title too: I'd like to define a type (CardOfType deck) which takes some deck of type Deck as a parameter.  I guess you can't do this, but I don't know.

What I want to do (basically, have a set of objects, each of which is a set of objects) seems like a basic thing - I bet people have run into similar problems before, and I'm hoping that there's some nice structural way to sort this out that I don't know about.

**Edit 2:** Based on Philip JF pointing me towards GADTs (=generalized algebraic data types) and doing some reading, I've realized that the thing I was looking for is called "Dependent types".  So my original title "types with parameters" doesn't sound so ridiculous.  It seems that these don't exist in Haskell.  I've found the papers that talk about simulating them, and read about Ωmega which apparently supports functions of types.  I still don't know if there exists a language that has types which take values as parameters.

Comment: I'm not totally clear on what you want to do or why, but have you looked into Algebraic data types?  Failing that, why not go with tuples?  It seems like the issue here is data tagging, since you want it to be open-ended.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I had a quick look at algebraic data types on HaskellWiki and Wikipedia and I don't think they're what I'm looking for - they'll do unions but it seems you still have to define each particular union in advance, plus that's only one thing I want to do.  I don't know what "data tagging" is.  I wonder if creating new classes could be useful, but I don't see how.

Comment: By data tagging, I just meant having a field that's part of your data that holds the label in question (eg: suit type).

Answer (score 3):

Haskell's type system can do almost anything if you are willing to use advanced features, but I would discourage using most of these early on while learning Haskell.  In your case, I would probably model it like so

```
data Card s v = Card {suit :: s, value :: v}
```

then define a suit like

```
data UsualSuit = Club | Diamond | Heart | Spade deriving
data FlowerSuit = Rose | Daisy | Poppy
```

this does most of what you want.  For example, it is easy to define compound suits like

```
data Rubies = Rubies
type UsualOrRubies = Either UsualSuit Rubies
```

I think this completely solves your needs in the static case.  When you have a user who enters in a suit dynamically, things are more complicated.  One option is to be "stringly typed"

```
type StringySuit = String
```

you could do something using `GADTs` but unless you give a larger example of what your problem is, I don't know what the problem with the `String` based solution would be.  It actually is possible to effectively "create types at runtime" using GADTs, but it is likely to be confusing for a beginner.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  Maybe I didn't make this clear, but I want to avoid defining all my suits in the code, as I don't know what they'll all be in advance.  I've edited the question to reflect this.  If this necessitates uses advanced features, I'm prepared to look into them.

Comment: Also, could you elaborate on the "stringly typed" option?  It looks similar to how I've defined my Suit type in my "nonsense code" above, but I don't know how I'd use it with e.g. the Card type you've defined.

Comment: being "stringly typed" just means using `String` as the type of the suit.  IE, use `Card String StandardCardValues` or something like that.  It is an alternative to using the types I defined.  Combining them is possible, but it is going to be tricky (something like GADTs).  The point is to define you code to work for *any* suit type, that way you can do things with static safety when it makes sense, but just use strings when necessary.